# Slow write speed on USB 3.0 thumb drive

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive

I am achieving approximately 6 - 7 MB/sec writes to a USB drive.  According to Wikipedia the theoretical speed is over 300 MB/sec.  Even allowing for marketing hype, this is a very large gap.

My system is 64 bit Windows 10 fully updated.  The cpu is an AMD 3950X and the motherboard is an ASRock X570 Pro 4.

I have tried the following with out success

enabling write caching in settings

updating driver

I also looked into upgrading the file system to NTFS with a large partition size.  But a 1TB drive looks like it will take several hours to format.  The thumb drive is brand new but a no name brand - could that be an issue?

I also found a recommendation to check if the mother board had USB 3.0 enabled but can't find the setting on the BIOS menu.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did the thumb drive come with any specifications? The theoretical speed is the maximum possible for the interface, not what devices connected via that interface are capable of.

Comment: Also, as a no-name brand, it may not have a 1 TB capacity.

Comment: Just because the theoretical speed is "over 300MB/s" doesn't mean that the drive is capable of it. Most flash drives have far better read speeds than write speeds and cheap drives will have far worse speeds.

Comment: The brand is Wedcook.  It was highly rated on Amazon but did not give an actual write speed other than to say "high speed".  It does have a 1TB capacity.  Does any one have a recommendation for a better flash drive brand?

Comment: What's the Amazon link or ASIN for the product? The only Wedcook 1 TB flash drive I can see there is 1) Says 128 GB in the details of the listing! 2) While it has a lot of stars, it's only by 60 reviews and almost all of them from Vine product sponsored reviews 3) On one of the product pictures it lists the write speed as 8-12 MBps

Comment: ***"It does have a 1TB capacity"***. Is that verified by actual writes to the device (see my Answer for utilities to do that)? The listed speed - even what shows up in the computer - can be faked by devices to look like it's 1 TB while being way less, and this is a lot of times the case with cheap devices. ***"Does anyone have a recommendation for a better flash brand?"*** Maybe, but a 1 TB Falsh Drive from any reputable brand will cost you like 5x the price

Comment: @Yisroel. You are looking at the drive I bought.  I do see the 128GB in the details. The description says 1TB and that’s what Explorer reports.  I guess I’ll know when I fill it up!

Comment: You might not even know when you fill it up with data, just when you try to read it back and the files are corrupted. Do yourself a favor and do a full test on the device. (Remember, there is some reason it's a 5th of the price that you can find ANY 1TB Flash Drive from any manufacturer with even a bit of name recognition... "If it's too good to be true, then it isn't..." )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am achieving approximately 6 - 7 MB/sec writes to a USB drive. According to Wikipedia the theoretical speed is over 300 MB/sec. Even allowing for marketing hype, this is a very large gap.

The A555 motorway here in Germany allows for speeds over 300 km/h.
There are rarely cars moving there that could exceed that barrier.
Furthermore, those cars are pretty expensive.

The same applies to your USB pen drive. USB pen drives are at the lower end of the hierarchy of devices that use flash storage.
Your sustained speed of 6 to 7 MB/sec is perfectly OK.

> My system is 64 bit Windows 10 fully updated. The cpu is an AMD 3950X and the motherboard is an ASRock X570 Pro 4.

> I have tried the following with out success enabling write caching in settings updating driver

That is the wrong strategy to diagnose.

> The thumb drive is brand new but a no name brand - could that be an issue?

Yes, but even a brand like Sandisk has cheap product lines that are being sold during supermarket promotions.
Bad pen drives can be recognized by the lack of information about the sustained write speed on the enclosure. Ads typically refere to the much higher read speed.

> I also looked into upgrading the file system to NTFS with a large partition size. But a 1TB drive looks like it will take several hours to format.

No, even with your pen drive a quick format should last less than a minute, there is no need for a full format.

> I also found a recommendation to check if the mother board had USB 3.0 enabled but can't find the setting on the BIOS menu.

Your board has USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 connectors. Make sure to use a 3.0 socket. When in doubt about the transfer speed, even a 2,5'' inch rotating disk with 5400 rpm will exceed the speed of USB 2.0.
USB 2.0 typically ends at 35-45 MByte/sec. Speed above 50 MByte/sec suggests that you are using the USB 3.0 protocol.

Use h2testw to determine sustained drive speed with a different device. Make sure the drive is empty or at least well defragmented because fragmentation will make your drive speed drop.

I'd rather buy a 2,5'' SSD drive and put it into an enclosure of my choice than buying a 1 TB USB pen drive.

Comment: Thanks for the Quick Format suggestion. It did indeed take only a few seconds. And it has made a drastic difference in write speed. I now am getting over 200MB/sec. Not just as reported by Explorer - that jumps around a lot. But by calculating file size over time to copy. And I did verify the copy

Comment: @Numbiz 200 MB/s write speed is unheard of in pendrives, particularly sketchy and no-name ones. I suspect your testing methodology may be flawed

Comment: @Numbiz: full formats will just waste p/e cycles and result in write amplification as the drive itself can't discriminate between a write that's result of a format zero-fill write or some file you intend to write. After a full format (entire NAND - overprovisioned) is mapped to LBA since such drives lack support for TRIM.

Comment: Use exFAT over NTFS. It puts less stress on the drive p/e cycle wise.

Comment: Joep, what is "p/e"?

Comment: @Joep. Is there any advantage to a full format?  If not I’m wondering why it exists as it’s so much more expensive

Comment: @r2d3 p/e cycle - program / erase cycle.

Comment: @Numbiz it would 1. overwrite existing data, any LBA sector would read 00 00 00 etc.. 2. it forces writes and allows the drive to detect problems and act, quick format only writes to fraction of the drive.

Answer (score 0):

While I will not have a "way to fix it" for you, here are some clarifications and points to make that may help:

- The max theoretical USB 3.0 interface transfer 600MBps, is "theoretical" for a reason... it's almost never actually reached since it depends on the hardware connected to the interface as well as the operation being done
- USB Flash Drive actual read/write speeds are bottlenecked a lot by the controller and actual Flash memory (which need to serve/accept the data being transferred.) The speeds are usually listed in the drive's spec sheet (and when you look at common ones it's typically more in the range of 130MBps read and 40MBps writes, even for good USB 3.0 flash drives)
- The speed also depends on the size of the files (a lot of small files will be way slower than one big files of their combined size) since the controller needs to do a lot of stuff for each file it is writing, and each file also needs to start on a new block)
- The write speed is further limited (even from the write speed this flash drive is supposed to have) by the OS and the Copying application you use (a tool like `robocopy` can be faster than Windows File Explorer copy)
- "***no name brand***". Yeah, that might be quite an issue. If it's not from a trustable brand, nothing that it said to be mightn't be true at all. It might not actually be USB 3.0 (but it does look like it, since write speed on USB 2.0 were typically even slower than that), and might very well not actually be 1TB (you should really run a test like one of the tools listed [here](https://www.geckoandfly.com/22803/detect-fake-usb-flash-drives-sd-cards-ssd-disk/), or else you risk ending up with corrupted data)

Comment: I am copying large (multi gigabyte) file and tried both File Explorer and custom software that achieves 200 - 300 MB/sec on hard drives. I will try reformatting the flash drive to NTFS with a large partition size (an overnight operation) and report the results tomorrow. Thanks for testing tools recommendation

Comment: **"large partition size"**. Maybe you mean "large allocation unit size" since partition size is not relevant.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I meant allocation unit size